# Does declaring a class variable is the same as declaring it within the __new__ method?

Tags: python, class, static

I would like to know if the two approaches are equivalent:

Approach 1

```
class A:
    toto = 1
```

vs, Approach 2:

```
class A:
   def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
       cls.toto = 1
       return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

To me they look the same. Especially, printing `dir(A)` gives the same result:

```
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 ...
 'toto']
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, not *exactly* the same, doing this in `__new__` does it *every time you instantiate an `A` object*. So, suppose you do `A(); A.toto = 10; A(); print(A.toto)` it will print `1`, but if you do with approach 1, `A(); A.toto = 10; A(); print(A.toto)` it will print `10`

Comment: Also, a terminology note, Python doesn't really *have* variable declarations, unless you mean type annotations, which sort of work that way, or `global`/`nonlocal`. But those two are special cases. In general, you never declare variables in Python. You simply define them and they pop into existence without declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these are not equivalent.

Approach 1 only sets the class variable *once*. Approach 2 sets it possibly 0 or many times, as many times as you instantiate an `A` object.

Consider the simplest case:

```
>>> class A:
...     toto = 1
...
>>> print(A.toto)
1
```

However:

```
>>> class A:
...    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
...        cls.toto = 1
...        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
...
>>> print(A.toto)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'toto'
```

Now consider a more complicated case:

```
>>> class A:
...     toto = 1
...
>>> a = A()
>>> A.toto = 42
>>> a = A()
>>> print(A.toto)
42
```

However:

```
>>> class A:
...    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
...        cls.toto = 1
...        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
...
>>> a = A()
>>> A.toto = 42
>>> a = A()
>>> print(A.toto)
1
```

Comment: Hi, Does the same apply to private variables in class as well? Example: `class A: __toto = 1`

Comment: @High-Octane so, Python doesn't really have "private" variables. `__toto = 1` will get *name mangled* inside a class definition to `_A__toto`, but aside from that mangling, it will work exactly the same way. E.g. `class A: __toto = 1`, but then outside, `A._A__toto = 42; A(); print(A._A__toto)` will behave the same